# How to add preseed file in Ubuntu ISO?

Tags: boot, 15.10, iso, preseed, remastersys

I am creating an .iso for Ubuntu 15.10 . I virtually mount it and placed the preseed file to the right path. Rebuild the ISO successfully, but it's not bootable. Used the command below to rebuild the iso:

```
# mkisofs -D -r -V "auto install" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o /home/hattori/ubuntu1404_auto.iso /home/hattori/serveriso
```

What is the cause of this problem . Please advise

Thanks

Anes